# Extracting data between curly brackets in text file in MATLAB

Tags: regex, matlab

I have a text file which has multiple lines and hierarchies like this:

```
...  
...
...
 Hierarchy { 


a {
     b {
      Name            "B1"
      Type            Virtual
       }
      c {
    Name            "C1"
    Parent          "B1"
      }
      d {
    Name            "D1"
    Type            Virtual
      }
}
a {
     b {
      Name            "B2"
      Type            Virtual
       }
      c {
    Name            "C2"
    Parent          "B1"
      }
      d {
    Name            "D2"
    Type            Virtual
      }
}
}
    ...
    ...
```

I am looking at extracting the text from "a {" till then end of the quotes matching "a" in MATLAB. The content inside "a" could vary in number of elements (there could be more than Name and Contains fields). Is there a way to extract "a" and possibly its fields into a cell array?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: where is `"a"` in your example?

Comment: @thewaywewalk , so far i have :                                                                               content = fileread('test.txt')                                                                               [startIdx, endIdx]=regexp(content,'\{[^{}]+\}')                                                       
startIdx =    15    90
endIdx =     75   141
>> content(15:75) = {       a_Name          1       Virtual         0           }                                         I also need to Name string before the quotes (content 11:13) and similarly the Contains field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want the code to work for any number of object and with any name.

I'd recommend you store the objects in structs (but you could change the code to be full cell array if you wanted), and I guess you want code to work for N objects in the pattern you've specified. regexp and cell arrays usually wouldn't be the best thing to use here, recursion would. But, the code below should work for your example and any number of objects. Comments should help explain what's going on.

```
% open file
fid = fopen('input.txt');

% get line from file
tline = fgetl(fid);

% assign tokens
startToken = '{';
endToken = '}';

% initialise counters
bracketCount = 0;
objectCount = 0;

% initialise root object to store anything parsed from file
data = {};

% initialise children cell array which will store names of objects
children = {};

% while not finished file
while ischar(tline)
    % check for {
    indexStart = regexp(tline, startToken);
    % check for }
    indexEnd = regexp(tline, endToken);
    % if a { is found
    if ~isempty(indexStart)
        % increment bracket counter
        bracketCount = bracketCount + 1;
        % extract the item name
        item = strtrim(tline(1:indexStart-1));
        % if this is a root 
        if bracketCount == 1
            % increase object count
            objectCount = objectCount + 1;
            % initialise object in cell array
            data{objectCount}.name = item;
        % if not a root object (e.g. a)
        else
            % initialise item field in object struct
            data{objectCount}.(item) = [];
        end
        % keep track of item name
        children{bracketCount} = item;
        % optional to display line
        disp(['Start: ' tline])
    % if a } is found
    elseif ~isempty(indexEnd)
        % decrement bracket counter
        bracketCount = bracketCount - 1;
        % optional to display line
        disp(['End: ' tline])
    % no brackets so name value pair assumed
    else
        % split the line into 2 -> {name, value}
        nameValue = strsplit(strtrim(tline));
        % if the line isnt empty and there are 2 items 
        if ~isempty(nameValue) && numel(nameValue) == 2
            % assign the value (nameValue{2}) to the field (nameValue{1})
            % of the current child (children{bracketCount}) of the current
            % object (doc{objectCount})
            data{objectCount}.(children{bracketCount}).(nameValue{1}) = nameValue{2};
            % optional to display line
            disp(['Name:' nameValue{1} ', Value:' nameValue{2}])
        end
    end
    % get the next line from the file
    tline = fgetl(fid);

end

% close file
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: Hi @cwissy , I'm having some issues with nested loops. I have updated the example on top. In this case, the 'b','c' and 'd' get replaced by the latest definitions of the fields 'b','c' and 'd'. Output:                                                                          >> data{1}.b

ans = 

    Name: '"B2"'
    Type: 'Virtual'                                                                                        However, I am looking to store both the "b" fields. can you tell me how I can achieve this please? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution to store "a" and its fields into cellarrays could be:

```
fp=fopen('testo_parentesi.txt','rt');
go_on=0;
curly_cnt=0;
fields_cnt=0;
while(1)
% read the file by lines
   tline=fgetl(fp)
   if ~ischar(tline)
      break
   end
% extract fields
   [str,res]=strtok(tline);
% look for the desired (a) field
   if(strcmp(str,'a') && go_on == 0)
      go_on=1;
      continue
   end
   if(go_on)
% count '}' to catch two of them (end of "a" section)
      if(strcmp(str,'}') && curly_cnt < 2)
         curly_cnt=curly_cnt+1;
      else
         curly_cnt=0;
      end
      if(curly_cnt == 2)
         break
      end
% store the fields into cellarrays
      if(curly_cnt == 0)
         fields_cnt=fields_cnt+1;
         c{fields_cnt}=textscan(tline,'%s%s');
      end
   end
end
fclose(fp);
```

If it is not mandatory storing data into cellarrays, an alternative could be storing "a" fields into a struct variable:

```
fp_orig=fopen('input_file.txt','rt');
go_on=0;
curly_cnt=0;
key_word=0;
while(1)
% read the file by lines
   tline=fgetl(fp_orig);
   if ~ischar(tline)
      break
   end
% extract fields
   [str,res]=strtok(tline);
% look for the desired (a) field and initialize the struct
   if(strcmp(str,'a') && go_on == 0)
      go_on=1;
      key_word=key_word+1;
      data(key_word).name=str;
      continue
   end
% count '}' to catch two of them (end of "a" section)
   if(go_on)
      if(strcmp(str,'}') && curly_cnt < 2)
         curly_cnt=curly_cnt+1;
      else
         curly_cnt=0;
      end
      if(curly_cnt == 2)
         break
      end
      if(curly_cnt == 0)
% if the string contains a "{" it is a "sub_fild" entry point, then a
% sub_field is added to the struct
         if(strfind(res,'{'))
            data(key_word).(str)='is_asub_field';
            field=str;
         else
% else the string is a field of the "sub_fiels", then it is added to the
% struct
            tmp_res=strtrim(res);
            if(tmp_res(1) >= 0 && tmp_res(1) <= '9')
               data(key_word).(field).(str)=str2double(tmp_res);
            else
               data(key_word).(field).(str)=res;
            end
         end
      end
   end
end
```

In that case, the output will be

```
data = 

        name: 'a'
        Name: [1x1 struct]
    Contains: [1x1 struct]

>> data.Name

ans = 

     a_Name: 1
    Virtual: 0

>> data.Contains

ans = 

    Regions: 0
      Label: '       ""'
```

Hope this helps.